# Notification block getting called because of relationship to shared model

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am writing an app where I use `Realm` as caching layer for models fetched from my API. Therefore, whenever user navigates to a screen, I first fetch the data from the `cache` (Realm) and immediately display them while an async request for updates is running in the background. Once the data is fetched, `notificationBlock` on the old `Realm Collection` is triggered and the data is updated on the screen.

Now for the issue, most of my models are based on `one-to-many` relationship and therefore can have a relation to the same model. Let's take an example of `User` and `Task` models - each user can have many tasks and each task belongs exactly to one user. Now, let's say I add a new task to the `realm` including the user model (user not updated), all already existing tasks belonging to this user seem to get an update notification because the user model was also stored, however neither of those already existing tasks nor the user was actually modified.

Is there a nice way how to get around this?

Comment: Did you set up a notification block on your whole `Realm`? If you are displaying information only about a single user on UI, you should set up a `notification block` on that single `User` instance only and not on your whole `Realm`.

Comment: I set-up the notification block on the tasks collection where each task has a reference to the user.

Comment: If you are only interested in a single user's tasks, don't do that, since as you can already see you will receive a notification block even if no tasks associated with your user were updated. You should rather give a property to the user, which is a collection of linking objects (all tasks associated with this user) and this way if you set up a notification block on the linking objects, you will only be notified when you need to be.

Comment: You are completely right, I will change my implementation :-)